# Dúvida WPF C# - SetFocus em um Text e deixar um button desabilitado

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou com dificuldade em c# pois quando clico em um botão, ele tem que desabilitar um botão e deixar o focus em um txt.
Porém não sei como referenciar um objeto em wpf (xaml) no arquivo de codificação (cs)

```js
  private void View(object parameter)
  {
    //Como referênciar o button01 e o txt01 aqui?
  }
```

```html
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Command="{Binding SearchCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
        Visibility="{Binding ShowList}"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonProcurar}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        
<Button x:Name="button01" Content="Desabilitar ao clicar no botão acima" />

<TextBox x:Name="txt01" Text="Texto que o cursor deverá vir ao clicar no primeiro botão" />
        <!-- C# WPF XAML -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você acessa os elementos do XAML pelo mesmo nome dado ao elemento na propriedade x:Name.
Neste caso os nomes dos elementos é button01, txt01.

Portanto, para desabilitar o botão e colocar o foco no campo de texto, você deve alterar o evento Button_Click que está no code behind (arquivo cs do XAML)

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button01.Enabled = false;
        txt01.Focus();
    }
```

É importante lembrar que seu XAML deve referenciar o Arquivo CS:
No início do arquivo XAML você encontrará a declaração da tag Window e a respectiva referencia a classe.
Se o arquivo CS não encontrar os elementos declarados em seu XAML, possivelmente está faltando essa referência.

Veja o exemplo:

Arquivo XAML:

[image: Exemplo]

Arquivo CS:

[image: ExemploCS]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!